# The value xxx is not valid for yyy. Wrong datetime format

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, date, datetime

Hello I'm getting my dateTime from a input box with datepicker initialized with this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#CreationDate").datepicker({ autoclose: true, todayHighlight: true, language: "pl", format: 'dd/mm/yyyy' });
})
```

As You can see format is `dd/mm/yyyy` 
This is my model:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public int DeviceId { get; set; }
public string SerialNo { get; set; }
public System.DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
```

And when I try to input my model into database controller refuses because `Model.isValid=false`

If I change format to `mm/dd/yyyy` model is valid but this is no option because users don't want to enter data in Us format.
I put in web.config globalization line:

```
<globalization culture="en-GB"/>
```

with no effect
how should I modify my code?
or the only simpleen call controler action?

Comment: try with `dd/MM/yyyy`

Comment: I `tried dd/mm/yyyy` changing mm to MM will make difference?

Comment: mm is for minutes MM is for Month

Comment: Why you deleted answer with working solution?

Comment: i thought you are using jquery?

Comment: I changed the datepicker options as You suggested and it started working

Comment: Great :) but community friends suggested that i'm confusing, it is valid for C# but i don't know about jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem :** Your custom dateformat `dd/mm/yyyy` is invalid.

small `mm` is used to represent `Minutes` not `Month`.

**Solution :** You should use capital `MM` to represent `Month`.
so your Format should be  `dd/MM/yyyy`

[mm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) The minute, from `00` through `59`.
[MM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) The month, from `01` through `12`.

Try This:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#CreationDate").datepicker({ autoclose: true, 
    todayHighlight: true, language: "pl", format: 'dd/MM/yyyy' });
})
```

Comment: [documentation for datepicker](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/) doesn't suggest using capitals but I'll check this

Comment: Youre confusing the format string for jQuery UI DatePicker with the .NET DateTime fomrat string. This wont work.

Comment: Its bootstrap datepicker not jQuery UI and do'nt know why after change it started working. More strange that dd/mm/yyyy is correct according to the docs

Answer (score 1):

This blog post should answer your question; http://weblogs.asp.net/melvynharbour/archive/2008/11/21/mvc-modelbinder-and-localization.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Your datepicker format should be `dd/mm/yy` instead of `dd/mm/yyyy`. In my case the following code works greate:

```
$(function () {
    $(".datePicker").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        yearRange: "2013:2014"
    });
});
```

Please note another thing, you may change CreationDate field from System.DateTime to String.

Then, use the following code

```
 DateTime CreationDate ; 
 DateTime.TryParseExact(yourModel.CreationDate, "dd/MM/yyyy", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out CreationDate );
```

Hope, this will help.